# How to really send a message to a user in Teams through a bot

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

The last few days, I checked dozens of samples, docs, blog posts, youtube videos (courses, that I couldn't fine) and I can say I'm still confused and I still without a Teams bot.
Every example I've checked is different in approach, and now I'm pretty sure there are many others like me.

Frequently problems: required input/parameters like service Url, conversation Id, **etc**. 1. You can't find a explanation for them.  2. You can't find a place where it's explained how to get them.

**What I want to achieve**

I want a bot on Teams, with a API, with 2 parameters: user email, message. The bot has to send the message to the specified user. That's it.

**I'm looking how to:**

1. Create/Setup the Application
2. Create the actual Bot
3. Install the application to Teams

Comment: Could you please check this [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tutorials/get-started-dotnet-app-studio). Try if that helps.

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT Will check it out, Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used to create a Teams conversation bot. Hope my experience will help you.

First, [download sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/57.teams-conversation-bot) provided by microsoft. I uses c# to create this bot, so I copy the '57.teams-conversation-bot' folder and opened it with vs studio. In this sample, I need to modify the configuration in appsettings.json. I need to enter the appid and apppassword.

So the next step is creating an Azure ad application in Azure portal. But if you never [create Bot Framework registration resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart-registration?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) before, you can create the azure ad application when you create a Bot Framework.By the way, You can leave 'Messaging endpoint' empty now.  **Please note**, when you creating Azure ad application, you can choose to set this application as a **multitenant** app if your account creating the app is in a different tenant with your teams account.

Now I have a bot framework and an Azure ad app, I can modify appsettings.json, enter the appId and app password. I can get appId in app overview page and get app password when creating client secrets in Certificates & secrets tag.

Now, I need to debug my sample with web chat in the azure portal(Enter the bot framework created just now, you can see Tag 'Test in web chat' in the left panel). So I need to use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to make the bot visit my code in local environment. Running the sample by pressing F5 in vs studio. Opening ngrok.exe and running the command `ngrok http -host-header=rewrite 3978`. Then I can get a https url, copy that and paste in the 'Messaging endpoint'. Don't forget to add '/api/messages'.
[image]
[image]

Now sending 'hello' to the bot and you will get default result. When you get the picture below, it means you have made a correct configuration.
[image]

Next step is to add this bot to Teams client. First, I add the Teams Channel in the bot I created in the azure portal.
[image]
[image]

Then I need to modify the manifest file. Replacing the "YOUR-MICROSOFT-APP-ID" with appId creating just now. And creating `manifest.zip` file which contains the three file in folder TeamsAppManifest.
[image]
[image]

Next step is uploading the zip file to Teams client. Click the 'Apps' in the lower-left corner and click the 'Upload the custom app' in the bottom of the left panel, then click add. Ok, now I get a team conversation bot.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There -are- a ton of approaches, partly because Teams development is still relatively new, partly because the Bot Framework (the set of tools for buildings Bots in the Microsoft world, both for Teams and otherwise) has also undergone some major changes. That's aside from the various language options (dotnet, node, python, etc.).

What's looking to be a good place to get started though, is the new Teams Toolkit, a plugin for Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code, for building a new Teams project (Tab, Bot, etc.). Have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/toolkit/visual-studio-code-overview) for a link. It's very new though, so some rough edges, but it's aiming to be very comprehensive to get up and running quickly (does a lot of Azure registrations behind the scenes, for example). Check out the latest monthly Teams Developer call, from earlier this week, for a visual run-through: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLWZJrkeLOrbbTKzV1sQOFAXd_s0BHJDiL (this week's call isn't up yet, but it should be very soon).