# How to schedule and send the message in MS teams bot

Tags: .net-core, microsoft-graph-api, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams

I have created a teams bot and had a service written in .NET core to handle the user's messages to reply accordingly. However I wanted to schedule a message and send it to the user(i.e. initiate conversation from bot).
I have gone through the online available sources, most of which refer the documentation for sending proactive message. But it didn't help as in my scenario I want to initiate a conversation on a specific time of the day and I am not getting in which event handler I can write the code. 
I also tried Azure functions as it can be scheduled and try to write code for sending message in teams, but I got some package related errors which I am not able to resolve. 
I am looking for a solution in the service I already have, if possible. Nonetheless anything will work.
A sample of code will be very helpful, as I am not much experienced in bot programming.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: To send messages proactively using your bot, you need to use "proactive messaging". You can find more info @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-proactive-messaging, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think my experience will help you. Some days before I got a request to make Teams bot send proactive message to a chat group at a specific time. My idea was `creating an Api in my code and setting a time trigger to make my function call this Api`. And it really worked.

Here's my function code, and you can know about how to set time trigger in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp#ncrontab-expressions):

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");


HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://xxxteamsbot.azurewebsites.net/api/sendProactiveMesg");
request.Method = "GET";

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream myResponseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
}
```

Here's my Controller:

```
[Route("api/sendProactiveMesg")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ProactiveController : Controller
    {
        public async Task sendProactiveMesg()
        {
            ProactiveMesgChannel a = new ProactiveMesgChannel();
            await a.sendtoGroupChat();
            //ProactiveMesgPersonal a = new ProactiveMesgPersonal();
            //await a.sendtoPersonal();
        }
    }
```

Here's my proactive message code:

> You can get **groupChatConversationId** and **serviceUrl** by using
> Filder to catch the request detail when your target message receiver
> is chatting with the bot.
> **BotClientId** and **BotClientSecret** are from Azure ad application.

```
public async Task sendtoGroupChat()
        {
            
            string groupChatConversationId = "19:5~~~f72c@thread.v2";
            string serviceUrl = "https://s~~~t/amer/";
            string botClientID = "e~~~c";
            string botClientSecret = "5z~~~A";
            AppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(serviceUrl);
            ConnectorClient connectorClient = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(serviceUrl), new MicrosoftAppCredentials(botClientID, botClientSecret), true);
            IMessageActivity message = await showTeamStatus();
            await connectorClient.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(groupChatConversationId, (Activity)message);
        }

        private async Task<IMessageActivity> showTeamStatus()
        {
            GetAnswersDetail detail = new GetAnswersDetail();
            List<ResData> res = await detail.GetDetailByIds();
            HeroCard card = new HeroCard();
            card.Title = "Status In " + getMonth();
            string html = "<div>Here is the detail view";
            html = (card.Text = html + "</div> ");
            return MessageFactory.Attachment(card.ToAttachment());
        }
```

By the way, if you are new to Teams conversation bot program, I think my another answer will help you to [create a bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64888619/how-to-really-send-a-message-to-a-user-in-teams-through-a-bot/64889875#64889875).  And to know about how to send proactive message, watch this [document](https://www.vrdmn.com/2020/02/microsoft-bot-framework-v4-send.html).