# How to send proactive message in botframework with python

Tags: python, multithreading, azure, botframework

Hello guys in this example: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/python/16.proactive-messages. The proactive message is sent only if you click on the link (in the bot framework emulator).

What i have to do is send a proactive message every day at 9:00 AM, so without click any link. I tried to create a thread and run it, but i have everytime in every solution the same error:
"RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'schedule_event' was never awaited
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback"

This is the code that i try. every 10 seconds is only for a test:

```
def print_action():
print('ok')

async def schedule_event():
schedule.every(10).seconds.do(_send_proactive_message)
while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()

if __name__ == "__main__":
try:
    a_thread = threading.Thread(target=schedule_event)
    a_thread.start()
    web.run_app(APP, host="localhost", port=CONFIG.PORT)
except Exception as error:
    raise error
```

So how i should do a function for start a job at 9:00 AM, that send a notification to user?

Comment: Can [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65092100/how-to-schedule-and-send-the-message-in-ms-teams-bot/65101452#65101452) help you?

Comment: @Tiny-wa don't think so